# Use a KMC X10 SL chain on an 11 Speed cassette?

Tags: chain, shimano, compatibility, specialized-bikes

I have two KMC X10 SL chains that I never ended up using. I got my new bike, which came with a KMC X11 chain (the bike is Specialized Diverge Comp). I am wondering if I can use the X10 chain on this bike?

Comment: 11 speed chains are a bit narrower than 10 speed chains (by about a half mm I think) and the cassette spacing is narrower too. If you have a 11 speed RD (which you do), the cage is also likely a bit narrower. For these reasons, I'd probably just opt for an 11 speed chain.

Answer (score 2):

They will not work at all. Use an 11-speed chain.

If you use the 10spd chain, there is a good chance that it can:

- Jam in the rear derailleur jockey wheels
- Increase the friction on the cassette, which will:
- Increase wear on the chain's side plates, dramatically increasing the chances that the chain will break right in the middle of you hammering up a hill.
- It will also shift quite poorly.